# How to differentiate$ f(x+\alpha s)$ with respect to $\alpha$.

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and let $s \in \mathbb{R}^n, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

I am trying to calculate $\frac{d}{d\alpha}f(x+\alpha s)$.

Is this calculation correct?

$$\frac{d}{d\alpha}f(x+\alpha s) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{d}{d\alpha}(x_i+\alpha s_i) \frac{\partial}{\partial (x_i+\alpha s_i)}f(x+\alpha s)$$
$$ = <s,
\nabla f(x+\alpha s)>.$$

Comment: Looks like you are assuming $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, and not $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^n$ as you wrote.

Comment: Sorry yes. I have updated the answer

Comment: Seems right to me